# unity3d and lot of buttons - looking for a smooth way to handle it

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Im doing gui in Unity (ugui) right now and i want to make lot of buttons and transitions. Is there a smoother way to do it than using transition method with screen ID/few onclick methods with int parameter? I tried to do onClick method base on enums but its not possible to add enum method to ugui button (tried integer but it can be confusing with lot of buttons).

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question but if you can't use enum maybe you can use plain string? e.g. "PlayButton", "SettingsButton" etc.

Comment: I know it's not OOP though

Answer (score 0):

Nika Kasradze: putting method based on string in inspector in not a good idea. You need write same string in onClick method later, and writing two same strings in not a good idea.

I used custom button function. You just add it to button and it calls a function in UI manager called "onButtonClick" and pass button name as parameter. Then you have onButtonClick method where you set up all buttons using button names. You can use multiple buttons with same name to call one function or use unique name to call unique function. onButtonClick method is really easy to read and you dont have to set up every button in inspector!!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

{
    [RequireComponent (typeof(Button))]
    public class CustomButton : MonoBehaviour
    {

        void Awake ()
        {
            Button btn = GetComponent<Button> ();
            btn.onClick.AddListener (() => ManagerUI.Instance.onButtonClick (gameObject.name));
        }

    }
}
```

and you put something like this in ManagerUI

```
void onButtonClick(string buttonName){
switch(buttonName){
case "back_btn": GoBack();
case "openshop_btn": OpenShop();
case "closepopup_btn": ClosePopup();
}
}
```